# How to implement a custom shape actor in LibGDX?

Tags: java, user-interface, libgdx

I would like to know how to implement a custom shape actor for which a click listener would work. For example if a have a hexagonal button, the listener should activate when the cursor really is in the hexagon, and not a square hit box. I would like to know if there is a way to implement this, using the native LibGDX frameworks.